# Retrieve multiple relational data object from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc, dataset

I tried to get multiple datatable from a stored procedure in my ASP.NET Core MVC app side.

But I want to get three datatables from SQL Server but I couldn't. I tried to write API layer from this query with `FromSqlInterpolated`. But data retrieved is always null, how can create this retrieve object classes? I tried to use three lists in a single `sp_myPersonelSalesOrderInfosList` class. But lists return or mapped null.

How can I retrieve this SQL command to object ?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_myPersonalSalesOrderInfosList] 
     @OrderNumber NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Dt 1 
    SELECT TOP 1 
        OrderNumber,
        PLAN_AMOUNT Planamount,
        ID MppId
    FROM 
        PRODUCT_PLAN
    WHERE 
        OrderNumber LIKE '%' + @OrderNumber + ''
        AND isDeleted = 0;

    --dt2 
    SELECT 
        p.OrderNumber,  
        p.PLAN_AMOUNT Planamount,
        p.ID MppId,
        p.ProcessNo OpNo,
        m.MACHINE_CODE + '-' + m.MACHINE_NAME MachineInfo
    FROM
        PRODUCT_PLAN p
    JOIN 
        MACHINES m ON m.ID = p.MACHINE_ID
    WHERE 
        OrderNumber LIKE '%' + @OrderNumber + ''
        AND isDeleted = 0;

    --dt 3 
    SELECT 
        p.ID MppId,
        d.ID MppdId,
        d.PRODUCTION_AMOUNT ProductAmount
    FROM 
        PRODUCT_PLAN_DETAIL d
    JOIN 
        PRODUCT_PLAN p ON p.ID = d.MPP_ID
    WHERE 
        OrderNumber LIKE '%' + @OrderNumber + ''
        AND p.isDeleted = 0
        AND d.PRODUCTION_AMOUNT > 0;
END
```

Comment: I would personally suggest 3 stored procedures here. Dealing with procedures that return multiple datasets can be a pain at the best of times; especially when the 3 datasets have different definitions.

Comment: Either `reader.NextResult` or filling a `DataSet` should do the trick. Don't give sprocs names that start with `sp_` they're reserved names

Answer (score 1):

If you need a stored procedure for some reason, it seems to me, that you can  create 1 select query instead of 3. It will be the last Select with some changes. After this you can use Linq to get data that you want. The summary amount of data will be not much more or maybe even less than  if you return 3 data sets. In another case and @Larnu suggested it too, it would be better to separate this stored procedure to 3 stored procedures. Or you can use ADO.net and a data reader.

Comment: thank you sir, additionally; My main goal is display these data on jstree view. How can I relationally converted this seperate datatable data ? any sugfgestion?